# Write the product of two trig equations equal to one?

Tags: trigonometry

Solve: Write the product of two trig equations that is equal to one.

This one confuses me because I can think of trig equations that equal one, but I can't think of trig equations that I could multiply times eachother in order to equal one.

Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what equation you're thinking of that equals one, then we can tell you how to use that knowledge.

Comment: $(\cot x)(\tan x) = 1$

Comment: and what do you mean by trig equation? do you mean perhaps trig *function*?

Answer (score 1):

how about $$(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)(\sec^2x-\tan^2x)=1\times1=1$$
or, using the second bracket as the difference of two squares,
$$\sec^2x-\tan^2x=(\sec x-\tan x)(\sec x+\tan x)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)(\csc^2x-\cot^2x)=1\cdot1=1$$

Answer (score 0):

It need not be only algebraic, many *reciprocal* Trig relations exist, among them:

Trig

$$(\sec x-\tan x)(\sec x+\tan x)=1$$

$$ \tan ( 45^\circ -A ) \tan (45^\circ + A) = 1 $$

Hyperbolic

$$(\cosh x+\sinh x) (\cosh x-\sinh x) =1 $$

Complex Trig

$$(\cos  x+ i \sin x) (\cos  x- i \sin x) =1 $$

Geometrical

If a cone of semi vertical angle $\alpha$ is cut by a plane inclined at $\beta$ to axis then

$$ cos\alpha \cdot \sec \beta = 1 $$ and so on.